# How to solve these equations with $x^2$, $xy$, and $y^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Is there any good method to solve equations like this?
$$
\begin{cases} 2y-2xy-y^2=0\\2x-x^2-2xy=0\end{cases}
$$
This is what I did:
$$
\begin{cases} y(2-2x-y)=0\\x(2-x-2y)=0\end{cases}
$$
now I see, that:
$$
x=0
$$
$$
y=0
$$
and it's the first solution, now:
$$
\begin{cases} 2-2x-y=0\\2-x-2y=0\end{cases}
$$
and:
$$
x=\frac{2}{3}, y=\frac{2}{3}
$$
I have 2 solutions, but wolfram found more...
Is there any good method for equations like this?

Comment: Why didn't you plug $x=0$ in the first equation and see what you will get!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are on the right track, but need to consider your cases carefully.

Case 1. $y= 0$, $x=0 $.
Done.

Case 2. $y=0 $, $2-x-2y = 0$.
Do this.

Case 3. $2-2x-y = 0$, $x = 0$.
Do this.

Case 4. $2-2x-y = 0$, $2-x-2y = 0$.
Done.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

From the first equation either $y=0$ or $2-2x-y=0$

If  $y=0,$ from the second equation $2x-x^2=0\implies x(x-2)=0\implies x=0,2$

If $2-2x-y=0,y=2-2x$ from the second equation  $2x-x^2-2x(2-2x)=0\implies x(3x-2)=0\implies x=0$ (which has been found already) and $x=\frac23$

Similarly start from the second equation

Answer (score 2):

You have two equations, each of which offers you two possibilities.
$$y(2−2x−y)=0 \implies  y=0 \text{ or }2-2x-y=0$$
$$x(2−x−2y)=0\implies x=0 \text{ or }2-x-2y=0$$

You have to try each possibility from the first equation with each option from the second to see which of the pairs give a solution.